# How to hide a video atfer it has been read in JS/CSS? (+ set a timer for it to be launched only once an hour)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website and, on the opening of the homepage, I have a poster of a video inviting to enter the website, then after clicking on the poster my video (MP4 format) is read.

I tried to do some JS/CSS stuff to hide it after it has been read but I must miss something in the process, that's why I'm asking for some help.

My actual code in the parts where we are interested about :

```js
function videoEnded() {
  var element = document.getElementByClassName("fullscreen-bg-video");
  element.classList.add("hidevideo");
}
```

```css
.fullscreen-bg-video.hidevideo {
  display: none;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.fullscreen-bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video controls class="fullscreen-bg-video" poster="https://www.ffk-    music.fr/wpcontent/themes/themeffk/img/poster-video-intro.jpg" onended="videoEnded()">
    <source src="https://www.ffk-music.fr/wp-content/themes/themeffk/videos/animffk1920x1080-compressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

I may have missed something about the JS part, and even after some research I didn't found any fitting solution.

Moreover, for the same video, I want it to be displayed only once an hour or so if a visitor already came by the homepage, can I add something in this order and what should I look for in order to find an answer to this?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `getElementsByClassName` returns array like data structure so you need to get the element from it using array index.
- It should be `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName`. Difference is `s`.

```js
function videoEnded() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen-bg-video");
  console.log(element)
  element[0].classList.add("hidevideo");
}
```

```css
.fullscreen-bg-video.hidevideo {
  display: none;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.fullscreen-bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video controls class="fullscreen-bg-video" poster="https://www.ffk-    music.fr/wpcontent/themes/themeffk/img/poster-video-intro.jpg" onended="videoEnded()">
        <source src="https://www.ffk-music.fr/wp-content/themes/themeffk/videos/animffk1920x1080-compressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can't believe I missed the "s" in the name even if I'm not very familiar with JS. It is working now, will look for something to display it only once an hour :)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementByClassName` does not exists, you probably want `getElementsByClassName`. Then you have to access an array element.

```js
function videoEnded() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen-bg-video");
  element[0].classList.add("hidevideo");
}
```

```css
.fullscreen-bg-video.hidevideo {
  display: none;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.fullscreen-bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video controls class="fullscreen-bg-video" poster="https://www.ffk-    music.fr/wpcontent/themes/themeffk/img/poster-video-intro.jpg" onended="videoEnded()">
    <source src="https://www.ffk-music.fr/wp-content/themes/themeffk/videos/animffk1920x1080-compressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Same answer than before, both helped me a lot